# Обновление datagridview с сортировкой после добавления новой строки в datatable

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

С помощью кода ниже (c# winforms vs2010 net4.0) на форму1 при запуске загружается Таблица1 (3 столбца) в datagridview (эта таблица привязана к контролу через bindingsource1). Затем по кнопке btnNewP добавляется новая строка в datagridview. Вопрос: как исправить код для кнопки btnSaveP, чтобы после сохранения перезагружался (обновлялось содержимое) datagridview с учетом сортировки строк по столбцу "поле1"?
Вариант с сортировкой в datagridview как новый dataView не удобен, т.к. при добавлении строки в datagridview и потери фокуса она автоматически сортируется по списку, поэтому хотелось бы сортировать строки в самой таблице, т.е. добавить строку, отсортировать в таблице1, и вернуть в datagridview.

```
namespace Prog
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\base.mdb";
        OleDbConnection conn;
        OleDbCommand cmd;
        OleDbDataReader dr;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter da;
        private BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

        private DataSet InitializeDataSet()
        {
            conn = null;
            try
            {
                conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();
                DataTable schemaTable;
                schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
                for (int i = 0; i < schemaTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    String strTable = schemaTable.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                    cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + strTable, conn);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    ds.Tables.Add(strTable);
                    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + strTable, conn);
                    da.Fill(ds, strTable);
                }
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return ds;
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataSet ds = InitializeDataSet();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bindingSource1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Таблица1"];
            dGV.DataSource = bindingSource1;
        }

        private void btnNewP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //добавление новой строки
        {
            try
            {
                DataRow myRow1;
                myRow1 = ds.Tables["Таблица1"].NewRow();
                ds.Tables["Таблица1"].Rows.Add(myRow1);
                bindingSource1.MoveLast();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
                this.Close();
            }
        }

        private void btnSaveP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //сохранение после добавления новой строки
        {
            try
            {
                for (int i = ds.Tables["Таблица1"].Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (ds.Tables["Таблица1"].Rows[i].RowState == DataRowState.Added)
                    {
                        bindingSource1.EndEdit();

                        string sqlAdd = "INSERT INTO Таблица1 (поле1,поле2,поле3) VALUES (@поле1,@поле2,@поле3)";
                        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlAdd, conn);
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
                            da.InsertCommand = conn.CreateCommand();
                            da.InsertCommand.CommandText = sqlAdd;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@поле1", ds.Tables["Таблица1"].Rows[i]["поле1"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@поле2", ds.Tables["Таблица1"].Rows[i]["поле2"]);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@поле3", ds.Tables["Таблица1"].Rows[i]["поле3"]);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            ds.Tables["Таблица1"].AcceptChanges();

                            conn.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                            bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);
                            conn.Close();

                            this.Close();
                        }
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                bindingSource1.ResetBindings(false);

                this.Close();
            }
        }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Данный код не тестил, да и для примера он, а так же можно попробовать применить запросы (from ... in ... orderby ... select ...)

```
            DataRow myRow1;
            myRow1 = ds.Tables["Таблица1"].NewRow();
            ds.Tables["Таблица1"].Rows.Add(myRow1);
            bindingSource1.MoveLast();

            //скорее всего так

           DataTable Sorttable= ds.Tables["Таблица1"];
           DataView view = Sorttable.AsDataView();
           view.Sort = "поле1 desc" или "поле1 asc";
           bindingSource1.DataSource = view;
```